# Arrayformula for running MAX of separate column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I'm trying to use `ARRAYFORMULA` in Google Sheets to get the max figures from a separate column only up to the row being calculated each time but can't for the life of me figure out how. It sounds more complicated than it actually is. This is what I have by using normal formulas:

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Always give expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(       A2:A,         "limit "&COUNTA(A2:A)), 
 QUERY(OFFSET(A2:A, -1, 0), "limit "&COUNTA(A2:A)-1)}),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(, IF(LEN(A2:A),
 "max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2"),
 "limit "&COUNTA(A2:A)),
 {""; QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY(       A2:A,         "limit "&COUNTA(A2:A)),
 QUERY(OFFSET(A2:A, -1, 0), "limit "&COUNTA(A2:A)-1)}),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(, IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2 
  limit "&COUNTA(A2:A)-1)}}),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(, IF(LEN(A2:A),
 "max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10zUu1ExPGcJUDZZYYaNL8m0T3vmbQvp3w5IcfWJ_ik4/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I get a "#REF!" error with the description: "Error:Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1. Actual: 2."

Comment: @pbu50w answer updated and added demo sheet. (side note: due to offset this needs to be run from 2nd row onwards)

Comment: Thanks. The formula seems to work up to a point (only row 11). If I have a large list the results break down after row 11 when adding more data. See my demo sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12mqQgQD3l0euQ51ZBUo-7qeSNW5-WEFRKYuFS7rVXuY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @pbu50w indeed this works only unless there are two consecutive rows with values lower than total acquired max. it could be tweaked to account for more consecutive rows. is your dataset predictable enough that you could say how many rows could have the lower value than acquired max?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The datasets I will be using this with are dynamic and unpredictable and will vary in length considerably (some being many hundreds of rows). Is there anywhere with an explanation or breakdown of how this formula works so I can understand it better? (Thanks for your input so far).

Comment: not rly, I just came up with it and basically, it works on this principle: it takes a column of values, creates duplicate of that column offset by one row. then it compares these two columns row by row to find max value in each column and then again will duplicate that column and offset it by one row and repeat the process - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqcib.png (can be seen at columns K-O) and then its all collapsed under one-cell-solution. here is my playground sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmMe29Jb9JSoL02gFV5bIh8JEubKecIhJlO5zOlREh4/edit#gid=636454129